# Once an order is placed, how to fetch order details automatically in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento.

I want to fetch the order details (**order_id, Product ID, SKU, Quantity, price, Shipping address, shipping method**) from Magento.

My main concern is I wanted to store all the information in a new single table, I am developing one custom PHP application for myself.

I got this code, but I really don't know where I have to create page and load the data:

```
<?PHP
$orderNumber = 145000013;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
// get order item collection
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($orderItems as $item){
$product_id = $item->product_id;
$product_sku = $item->sku;
$product_name = $item->getName();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$category_id = $cats[0]; 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$category_name = $category->getName();
echo "orderNumber=".$orderNumber."<br/>";
echo "orderValue=".$orderValue."<br/>";
echo "product_name=".$product_name."<br/>";
echo "product_id=".$product_id."<br/>";
echo "product_sku=".$product_sku."<br/>";
echo "category_id=".$category_id."<br/>";
echo "category_name=".$category_name."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

---

I got this code, but I really don't know where I have to create page and load the data

```
<?PHP
$orderNumber = 145000013;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
// get order item collection
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($orderItems as $item){
$product_id = $item->product_id;
$product_sku = $item->sku;
$product_name = $item->getName();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$category_id = $cats[0]; 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$category_name = $category->getName();
echo "orderNumber=".$orderNumber."<br/>";
echo "orderValue=".$orderValue."<br/>";
echo "product_name=".$product_name."<br/>";
echo "product_id=".$product_id."<br/>";
echo "product_sku=".$product_sku."<br/>";
echo "category_id=".$category_id."<br/>";
echo "category_name=".$category_name."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If it's an application external to Magento - you might want to use the API

Answer (score 0):

To load an order by increment id one would do:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001'); //use a real increment order id here
```

To load by entity id you would just call load:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999); //use an entity id here
```

Comment: then... what is the problem?

Comment: I got this code, but I really don't know where I have to create page and load the data

Comment: in that case learn to create a module first http://magenticians.com/create-magento-custom-module/

Comment: Thank you Raghu, I wanted to ask one more question. is there any way i can directly fetch order details from database tables.

Comment: in which tables all the orders details stored.

Comment: you should not do that magento never recommends this.. FYI, Magento uses EAV database structure that is built keeping in mind that direct query fetching should not be done... Please accept my answer.

Comment: please accert my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create file in root (i.e test.php) and try below coding.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$orderNumber = 145000013;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);
// get order item collection
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($orderItems as $item){
$product_id = $item->product_id;
$product_sku = $item->sku;
$product_name = $item->getName();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$category_id = $cats[0]; 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$category_name = $category->getName();
echo "orderNumber=".$orderNumber."<br/>";
echo "orderValue=".$orderValue."<br/>";
echo "product_name=".$product_name."<br/>";
echo "product_id=".$product_id."<br/>";
echo "product_sku=".$product_sku."<br/>";
echo "category_id=".$category_id."<br/>";
echo "category_name=".$category_name."<br/><br/>";
}
```

its working when you can get details externally.

Comment: Thank you, it is fetching data. can you please send me any link how can I fetch PRICE, Shipping address, USER email, user Phone from database

Comment: Try this.

$order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
OR
$custname = $order->getCustomer()->getName();